# RxJS global var for different streams

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

How I can create a global variable for different observables functions?

For example iteration number, or array where one observable object deleted from array, another one added and etc.

```
// RxJS v6+
import { fromEvent, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { mapTo, startWith, scan, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const setHtml = id => val => (document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val);

const addOneClick$ = (id, iter) =>
  fromEvent(document.getElementById(id), 'click').pipe(
    mapTo(10),
    startWith(0),
    scan((acc, curr) => {iter++; return acc + curr}),
    tap(setHtml(`${id}Total`)),
    // it changed only in this object
    tap(val => console.log(`${iter}`))
  );
const predefVar = 100;
const combineTotal$ = combineLatest(addOneClick$('red', predefVar), addOneClick$('black', predefVar))
//I need see chancged predefVar varible here
  .pipe(map(([val1, val2]) => `${val1 + val2} clicked: ${predefVar}`))
  .subscribe(setHtml('total'));
```

HTML view

```
<div>
  <button id='red'>Red</button>
  <button id='black'>Black</button>
</div>
<div>Red: <span id="redTotal"></span> </div>
<div>Black: <span id="blackTotal"></span> </div>
<div>Total: <span id="total"></span> </div>
```

Comment: what is stopping you from changing it in the `tap(val => ...)` (and declare it before `addOneClick$`)? And how are you going to change it if it is `const`?

Comment: because I looking for "ref" input variable in observable instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you passed primitive param in function, the value was copy as different variable. Whatever you assign, the global variable isn't be changed. This can be fixed if you define `object`, because it is passed as ref, its property can be changed.

If you define `predefVar` as global, just call it directly:

```js
var predefVar = 100;

const addOneClick$ = (id) =>
  fromEvent(document.getElementById(id), 'click').pipe(
    mapTo(10),
    startWith(0),
    scan((acc, curr) => {predefVar++; return acc + curr}),
    tap(setHtml(`${id}Total`)),
    // it changed only in this object
    tap(val => console.log(`${iter}`))
  );
```

However, depending on use case, you should avoid global variable as much as you can. In this case, you can use pure Rx.js like this: ([playground](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pZZKgK))

```js
const {
  of,
  merge,
  combineLatest,
  fromEvent
} = rxjs;

const {
  scan,
  mapTo,
  startWith,
  tap,
  map,
} = rxjs.operators;

const setHtml = id => val => 
  (document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val);

const addOneClick$ = (id) =>
  fromEvent(document.getElementById(id), 'click').pipe(
    mapTo(10),
    startWith(0),
    scan((acc, curr) => acc + curr),
    tap(setHtml(`${id}Total`)),
  );

const totalClick$ = (arr$, defaultValue) => 
  merge(...arr$).pipe(
    startWith(defaultValue - arr$.length),
    scan((acc) => acc + 1, defaultValue),
  );

const red$ = addOneClick$('red');
const black$ = addOneClick$('black');
const total$ = totalClick$([red$, black$], 100);

const combineTotal$ = combineLatest(
  total$, red$, black$,  
)
  .pipe(
    map(([total, val1, val2]) => `${val1 + val2} clicked: ${total}`)
  )
  .subscribe(
    setHtml('total')
  );
```

Comment: Thank you! "Scan", what i really looked for.

Answer (score 0):

You need it pass down from addOneClick$ if you want to avoid global variable.

```
const addOneClick$ = (id, iter) =>
  fromEvent(document.getElementById(id), 'click').pipe(
    mapTo(10),
    startWith(0),
    scan((acc, curr) => {iter++; return acc + curr}),
    map(res=>[res,iter])
    ....
)
```